# Import Thunderbird messages to Outlook for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I just got a copy of Office 2011 for the Mac.  I would like to import all my old email from Thunderbird into Outlook on my Mac.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Importing and exporting your mail - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Importing_and_exporting_your_mail)

Comment: Nice resource. +1 for you.